# Nuget SurveyMonkeyApi SSL/TLS Connection issue

Tags: c#, api, ssl, tls1.2, surveymonkey

I received the error **"*The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel*"** thrown at this line below.

```
List<Survey> surveys = api.GetSurveyList();
```

The exception thrown was that ***SurveyMonkey requires TLS 1.2, as of 13 June 2018*** however, the page is secure and after checking the browser security it shows ***The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2***

Please assist.

Comment: Which version of Windows and .NET are you using?

Comment: @Charlieface Windows 2016   .NETFramework v4.0

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using Framework 4.8 or other newer version

Comment: @Charlieface this is what was given

Comment: Then follow the instructions in the above link